# How to get aspect ratio of the video in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, media-player

I am using [Better_Player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) to display the video but I am not getting the aspect ratio of the video so how can I do it. if anyone having it would be great if you share.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and used BoxFit.scaleDown and it worked for me.

BetterPlayerConfiguration(
fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, you are not getting aspect ratio?

You can give the BetterPlayer attribute of aspectRatio.

```
BetterPlayer.network(
    "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
     betterPlayerConfiguration: BetterPlayerConfiguration(
        **aspectRatio**: 16 / 9,
     ),
  ),
```

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nafTM.jpg)
If that is not working, you can simply try to wrap the player in AspectRatio Widget, like the documentation example:

```
AspectRatio(
    **aspectRatio**: 10 / 9,
    child: BetterPlayer.network(
          "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
           ),
  ),
```

[Or like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQU2y.jpg)

Or am I not understanding the question right?

Comment: i dont want static. it should be based on video Aspect Ratio. Suppose if my video is in portrait orientation then it should appropriate aspect ratio.

Comment: It should be dynamic depending on the video. Otherwise the video stretches.  I tried:
 wrapping with an aspectRatio: _betterPlayerController.getAspectRatio() but i get an error.